# How to fix 'env: python: No such file or directory: on Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, environment-variables

I've recently removed the default version of `python2.7` on my Mac. When I tried to execute python code I got the following error:

```
env: python: No such file or directory.
```

I installed python3 with `home-brew` however I need `python2.7` and can't install with `home-brew`

How can I get back the original version `2.7` ?

Comment: have you looked into : https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2715/

Comment: Why you `can't install with home-brew`? Anyway: although your question is more OS/homebrew related than python but I recommend you to learn: `pip`, `virtualenv` and `pipenv`. Environment creation is basic skill in modern python.

Comment: Ugggh! You should never tamper with, or remove, anything in `/bin` and `/usr/bin` and which are supplied by your OS vendor. System updates and package installations rely on them being there and working in a predictable fashion. You should really only install or diddle with things in `/usr/local` and possibly `/opt`. I don't know of a way to re-install Apple-supplied Python.

Comment: Thanks for replying, i was trying to fix it all day, but I couldn’t  i’ve decided to reinstall mac os.